# How to convert javascript obj into URL parameters with nested object in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have a react app that handles routing in the application. I am getting json object from db with parameters that will look like this:

```
    let paramsObj = {
        state: {
            Corp: "CorpCode",
            Location: "LocationCode",
            IsCorp: false
        }
    };
```

How to convert paramsObj and encode it to URL parameters so the final string would look like this?state=%7B%20Corp%3A%20%22CorpCode%22%2C%20Location%3A%20%22LocationCode%22%2C%20IsCorp%3A%20false%20%7D

Answer (score 1):

```js
let paramsObj = {
    state: {
        Corp: 'CorpCode',
        Location: 'LocationCode',
        IsCorp: false,
    },
};

const urlSearchParams = Object.keys(paramsObj).reduce((output, key) => {
    const value = paramsObj[key];
    const valueString = JSON.stringify(value);
    output.append(key, valueString);
    return output;
}, new URLSearchParams());

console.log(urlSearchParams.toString());
```

Comment: It should work somehow in combination new URLSearchParams().toString(). your solution gives me link without "state=" part which should be taken from json object

Comment: You can do it with reduce as seen now

Comment: Is it ok that in this solution string is URI encoded two times? Like:
1.%7B%20Corp%3A%20%22CorpCode%22%2C%20Location%3A%20%22LocationCode%22%2C%20IsCorp%3A%20false%20%7D
2.%257B%2520Corp%253A%2520%2522CorpCode%2522%252C%2520Location%253A%2520%2522LocationCode%2522%252C%2520IsCorp%253A%2520false%2520%257D

Comment: You are right, it was a mistake, the encodeURIComponent encoding I added was redundant and is handled by URLSearchParams. I fixed the code block in the answer.